# WPF ContentControl set ZIndex to child ZIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to be able to set a Z-Index of a `ContentControl`, the parent, based on a child control that's inside the `ContentControl`.

Here's my tiny example:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100" Panel.ZIndex="5"/>
    <ContentControl>
      <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Panel.ZIndex="10" />
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

In this example, the Panel.ZIndex declared in the `Red` `Rectangle` has no effect.

I thought of two options:

- Have the parent bind to the `Panel.ZIndex` value of the child
- Have the child set the `Panel.ZIndex` on its parent

I couldn't figure out how to do either of these two options.

Eventually my child controls are defined in a `DataTemplate` which gets applied using a `ContentControl`, meaning I can't directly set the `Panel.ZIndex` property of the `ContentControl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100" Panel.ZIndex="5"/>
    <ContentControl Panel.ZIndex="{Binding Content.(Panel.ZIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Panel.ZIndex="10" />
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I messed up and need to use it for a `ContentPresenter` instead of a `ContentControl`. You answered my original question though :) (If you know an easy way for `ContentPresenter` feel free to add a comment)

Comment: A ContentPresenter is a different story. It has no Content property. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.